# Ramanujan's Nested radical Inequality

Tags: solution-verification, proof-explanation, functional-equations, nested-radicals

Recently I was studying functional equation, in which I came across this paragraph about **Ramanujan's Nested Radical** in Christopher G. Small's book [Functional Equations and How to Solve Them][1].

> $$ \sqrt{1+2\sqrt{1+3\sqrt{1+4\sqrt{1+\cdots}}}}=3. $$ assuming
> $$ f(x) = \sqrt{1+x\sqrt{1+(x+1)\sqrt{1+(x+2)\sqrt{1+\cdots}}}}=3.$$
> $$ [f(x)]^2 = 1 + x f(x+1) $$
> by degree analysis we get $ f(x) = x+1 $ (by assuming $f(x) = ax+b$ ,thus by substituting a,b =1)

Next comes the main part i.e the author **derives an inequality** before proceeding to proof.

> Now I'm providing the **derivation of inequality** as it is
>
> > for all $x \geq 1$
> > $$ f(x) \geq {\sqrt{x\sqrt{{x\sqrt{....}}}}} $$
> > $$ = x^{(1/2)+(1/4)+(1/8)+.....} $$
> > $$ = x $$
> > $$  \geq (x+1)/2 $$

Bounding on other side, We have

> $$ f(x) \leq {\sqrt{(x+1)\sqrt{{(x+2)\sqrt{{ (x+3)}....}}}}} $$
> $$ f(x) \leq {\sqrt{(x+1)\sqrt{{2(x+1)\sqrt{{ 3(x+1)}....}}}}} $$
> $$ f(x)   =   (x+1) {\sqrt{1 \sqrt{{2\sqrt{{ 3}....}}}}} $$
> $$ f(x)  \leq   (x+1) {\sqrt{1 \sqrt{{2\sqrt{{ 4}....}}}}} $$
> $$ f(x) = 2(x+1) $$

Thus

> $$ (x+1)/2 \leq f(x) \leq 2(x+1) $$

I can't understand the proceeding of Inequality. Is there any inequality used? Is it an approximation then how do it proceeds as such? (This inequality is used further to prove,(regards Thesimplifire for pointing out a typo) and available on the next page of book)

---

*Small, Christopher G.*, Functional equations and How to solve them, Problem Books in Mathematics. New York, NY: Springer (ISBN 978-0-387-34539-0/pbk). xii, 129 p. (2007). [ZBL1152.39300](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1152.39300).

Comment: The proof is literally on the next page of what you have pasted above. See Proposition 3.12, where it is shown that $2^{-2^{-k}}(x+1)\le f(x)\le2^{2^{-k}}(x+1)$ for all integers $k>0$, and taking $k\to\infty$ yields $x+1\le f(x)\le x+1$. So I'm not sure what you are really asking.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire Yeah Ok, but my main doubt is "How the author has derived this inequality"?

Comment: I am sure Ramanujan himself wouldn't give a satisfying answer of how he got this inequality

Comment: @XiChan Why so?